# AngularJS DataTable 0.6.2 doesn't load table data when using a variable in a column heading

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I'm using AngularJS DataTable 0.6.2 https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/changeOptions. I need a column title to be dynamic, using a variable in it. However when I do this, when I'm trying to update the table data it does not update, even the request (in the Chrome network) is bringing all the data correctly. The table only updates with the current data if I change the "results per page".

To make the column title dynamic, I'm defining the **dtColumns** again whenever the variable changes and placing it in the **withTitle()** function like this **withTitle(variableName)**

Therefore, the definition of the columns looked like this:

```
vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notSortable()
    ];
```

And changing the title of the specific column looked like this:

```
function changeColumns(variableName) {
        vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle(variableName),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notSortable()
        ];
    }
```

If in place of **variableName** I put the same name in which the column was defined, the table works normally.

Comment: Did you manage to handle the issue?